# Template Language for Django which does not silently fail on exception?

Tags: django, django-templates

I like django, the ORM, the admin, the community. But I don't like the handling of exception in the template language, like documented here: [invalid template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables).

Is there an alternative template variable where I always get an exception if something is wrong (even in production)?

I prefer exceptions to "silently ignore errors".

Comment: It's actually not failing silently, It's returning null which is nothing, and nothing in HTML works

Comment: But yes you can use jinja2 as documented

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed it I don't see anything where something should be, then this is for me "failing silently".

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to change your template backend to `jinja2` (which is supported "natively" by Django) [following the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration).

An in-depth explanation on how `jinja2` django backend handles the `undefined` variable issue, [can be found here](https://www.webforefront.com/django/jinjaconfiguration.html) *(notation mine)*:

> **Invalid template variables**
>
> You can set various behaviors when an invalid variable is encountered
>   in Jinja templates. Django sets Jinja with two default behaviors, one
>   for when `DEBUG=True` -- a common setting in development -- and the
>   other for when `DEBUG=False` -- a common setting in production.
>
> If `DEBUG=True` and an invalid variable is set in a Jinja template,
>   Jinja uses the `jinja2.DebugUndefined` class to process it. The
>   `jinja2.DebugUndefined` class outputs the variable verbatim for
>   rendering (e.g. if the template has the `{{foo}}` statement and the
>   variable doesn't exist in the context, Jinja outputs `{{foo}}`, making
>   it easier to spot an invalid variable).
>
> If `DEBUG=False` and an invalid variable is set in a Jinja template,
>   Jinja uses the `jinja2.Undefined` class to process it. The
>   `jinja2.Undefined` class outputs a blank space in the position of the
>   variable for rendering (e.g. if the template has the `{{bar}}` statement
>   and the variable doesn't exist in the context, Jinja outputs a blank
>   space). *It's worth mentioning this last behavior aligns with the
>   default behavior of invalid variables in Django templates.*
>
> In addition to the `jinja2.DebugUndefined` and `jinja2.Undefined` classes,
>   Jinja also supports the `jinja2.StrictUndefined` class. The
>   `jinja2.StrictUndefined` class is used to generate an immediate error
>   instead of proceeding with rendering, which is helpful for quicker
>   diagnosis of invalid variables. **However, be aware this last class
>   changes its behavior based on the `DEBUG` variable, it either generates
>   a stack error with the invalid variable name (i.e. when `DEBUG=True`) or
>   it generates a standard HTTP 500 error page (i.e. when `DEBUG=False`).**

If you like to set the `StrictUndefined` option on your template you can use the following example [from the same source](https://www.webforefront.com/django/jinjaconfiguration.html):

> **Listing 4-4. Generate error for invalid variables in Jinja with
>   `jinja2.StrictUndefined`**
>
> ```
> import os
>
> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
> PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
>
> import jinja2
>
> TEMPLATES = [    
>     { 
>         'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
>         'DIRS': ['%s/jinjatemplates/'% (PROJECT_DIR),],
>         'APP_DIRS': True,
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             'undefined':jinja2.StrictUndefined
>         },
>     }            
> ]
> ```
>
> As you can see in Listing 4-4, we first declare `import jinja2` to gain
>   access to Jinja's classes in `settings.py`. Next, we declare the
>   undefined key inside the `OPTIONS` parameter and assign it the Jinja
>   class to process invalid variables. In this case, we use the
>   `jinja2.StrictUndefined` class to get errors when invalid templates
>   variables are encountered, but you could equally use any of the other
>   two Jinja classes to handle invalid variables (i.e.
>   `jinja2.DebugUndefined` or `jinja2.Undefined`).

Finally, if you want to have a different behavior between `DEBUG=True` or `DEBUG=False` you can change the following in the `TEMPLATES` settings:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'undefined': jinja2.DebugUndefined if DEBUG else jinja2.StrictUndefined
},
```

Utilizing jinja2's debugging option on development and strict options on production (raising errors as is mentioned in the question).